# Payment method for google play subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play, google-pay

I am using google play subscription services for my app.But when any use or customer tries to pay for my subscription with any given payment method.It shows -

```
 Unavailable for this purchase.
```

Only I can pay with Google play account money.[image]

I tried all method  on different mobiles. But problem is same.

I am using standard code given on google developers site.

```
private BillingClient billingClient=BillingClient.newBuilder(activity)
.setListener(this).build();

billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingResponse.OK) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {

    }
});
```

I want to enable all payment methods for my app.

Comment: did you find the cause of problem and fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add enablePendingPurchases(), so

```
private BillingClient billing_client = BillingClient.newBuilder( this ).enablePendingPurchases().setListener(...
```